# Spring Boot method entry and exit logging not working

Tags: spring-boot

I have the following entry in my application.yml for logging, but it's not logging the method entry and exit. It's only logging the Tomcat server log.

**application.yml**

```
logging:
    file: ../logs/Audit_Management_DS.log 

level: DEBUG
```

I am deploying my application on Tomcat 8. I have tried this through application.properties, but it's not working. My entry in application.properties is as follows:

```
logging.file= ../logs/Audit_Management_DS.log 
logging.level.*=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework  = ON
```

Comment: And why should it log entry and exit? There is no such thing as entry/exit logging build into the framework...

Comment: Are you using Jhipster by any chance? If so, that's a jhipster feature I think. There's no such thing in Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

Your `application.yml` looks like it has whitespace errors, the '*' (asterisk) in your properties file probably should be "ROOT", and "ON" is not a valid log level. Fix some or all of those and see if it helps.

(But as the others said in comments, Spring Boot does not log method executions.)